# evaluate variable in xslt by using exslt evaluate

Tags: java, xslt

i'm using xslt dynamic evaluate (dyn:evaluate) but i have a problem, this evaluate function inside a loop and i want to evaluate on a different context not looping context, something like

`<xsl:variable name="recId" select="dyn:evaluate($targetContext,$list[1])"/>`
but dyn:evaluate has just one input which is a variable, so i had to do something like this
`<xsl:variable name="recId" select="dyn:evaluate($list[1])"/>`

here's also my template

> `<xsl:template match="hl7:controlActEvent/hl7:subject">
>
>           <xsl:for-each select="java:org.apache.xalan.lib.ExsltStrings.tokenize($xpath, ';')">
>
>               <xsl:variable name="list" select="java:org.apache.xalan.lib.ExsltStrings.tokenize(., ',')"/>
>
>    here's the problem, evaluation inside loop
>
>               <xsl:variable name="recId" select="dyn:evaluate($list[1])"/>
>
>               <xsl:variable name="createDate" select="dyn:evaluate($list[2])"/>
>
>               <xsl:choose>
>
>                   <xsl:when test="$createDate != '' ">
>
>                       <xsl:variable name="detailNode" select="$postDomainDoc/record_detail[record_id = $recId]"/>
>
>                       <xsl:choose>
>
>                           <xsl:when test="$detailNode/consent_status = 'deny' ">
>
>                               <hl7:subject typeCode="SUBJ" nullFlavor="MSK" xsi:nil="true"/>
>
>                           </xsl:when>
>
>                           <xsl:otherwise>
>
>                               <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
>
>                           </xsl:otherwise>
>
>                       </xsl:choose>
>
>                   </xsl:when>
>
>                   <xsl:when test="$createDate = '' and $ehipDecision = 'deny'">
>
>                       <hl7:subject typeCode="SUBJ" nullFlavor="MSK" xsi:nil="true"/>
>
>                   </xsl:when>
>
>                   <xsl:otherwise>
>
>                       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
>
>                   </xsl:otherwise>
>
>               </xsl:choose>
>
>           </xsl:for-each>
>
>       </xsl:template>`

Any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to evaluate the expression in the context of the node that the template matched, you could get most of the way there by capturing that node in a variable outside the `for-each`, and then "reset the context" with a nested `for-each`

```
<xsl:template match="hl7:controlActEvent/hl7:subject">
  <xsl:variable name="theSubject" select="." />
  <xsl:for-each select="java:org.apache.xalan.lib.ExsltStrings.tokenize($xpath, ';')">
    <xsl:variable name="list" select="java:org.apache.xalan.lib.ExsltStrings.tokenize(., ',')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$theSubject">
      <!-- rest of template goes here, . is now the hl7:subject again -->
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This will get `.` returning the right thing, but `position()` inside the inner for-each will always be 1, if you need access to the outer `position()` you'll have to similarly save that in a variable.